# Transform gradient to reference element

Tags: matrices, transformation, affine-geometry, finite-element-method

Minimal example of the problem

[image]

**How can you transform the gradient to the reference element?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General

The reference and the global basis functions are related by

\begin{equation}
\hat \varphi_i (\hat x) = \varphi_{n_i} (F_K (\hat x)) = \varphi_{n_i} (B_K \hat{x} + b_K), i = 1, 2, 3.
\end{equation}

This yields naturally relation between the gradient too. 
Assume gradients are column vectors too. 
Then, it holds too

\begin{equation}
\hat \nabla \hat \varphi_i (\hat x) = 
\hat \nabla \varphi_{n_i} (F_K (\hat x)) \\ =
\nabla \varphi_{n_i} ( F_K (\hat x) ) \cdot \hat \nabla F_K (\hat x) \\ = 
\nabla \varphi_{n_i} ( F_K (\hat x) ) \cdot \hat \nabla (B_K \hat x + b_K) \\ =
\nabla \varphi_{n_i} (x) \cdot B_K \\ = 
B_K^T \nabla \varphi_{n_i} (x)
\end{equation}
and so
\begin{equation}
\nabla \varphi_{n_i} (x) = B_K^{-T} \hat \nabla \hat \varphi_i (\hat x). 
\end{equation}

### **Consider $K_1$**

\begin{equation}
\varphi_1 (\hat x) = \varphi_2 (B_K \hat x + b_K)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
B_K = [n_2 - n_1; n_3 - n_1]
\end{equation}

and take

\begin{equation}
b_K = n_2.
\end{equation}

I think we just provided ways how to transform the gradient to the reference element.

### Sources

1. My lecture notes of Course Element methods, page 7 and Equation 13.